# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis: Live server failure detection frequency for backup?

Tags: activemq-artemis

In Apache ActiveMQ Artemis when live server goes down immediately the backup server changes its role to be live. I want to understand parameters behind this and whether we can fine-tune them.

1. What is the frequency which backup server notice live server no longer available. Is this configurable?
2. Is there a retry count which backup server tries to connect to live before deciding it should change its role to live?

Comment: Are you using replication or shared storage? The way each works is different so it's important to know which you are using in order to answer you question(s).

Comment: Currently we are using network replication. We hope to migrate to shared-storage soon.

Comment: So do you want the answer for both replication and shared storage or just one? If the latter, which one? Please clarify.